# Nonparametric alternative to a mixed-design ANOVA

Tags: r, anova, assumptions

I'm working on the statistical analysis of a listening test (based on the MUSHRA [1]) where I'm trying to compare the sound quality degradation introduced by the processing of 3 different algorithms.
I tested 20 subjects divided in 2 groups based on their nativeness (11 native speakers, 9 non-native speakers) and each subject rated each of the test signals (10 speech signals) processed through each of the 3 different tested algorithms, for a total of 10x3 = 30 evaluations per subject.

Test signals (*Audios*) AND Algorithms (*Algos*) are both within-subject factors.
Nativeness (*Nativ*) is a between-subject factor.
The *Scores* provided by each subject per each evaluation is a number in the range 0-100.

According to the standard describing the listening test, an repeated measurements ANOVA is recommended, including a Huynh-Feldt correction in order to account for departures from sphericity.

I managed to implement this in R using `ezANOVA` as:

```
  speech_values.ez <- ezANOVA(data=speech_values,        # specify data frame
      dv=.(Scores),              # specify dependent variable
      wid=.(PID),                # specify the subject variable
      between=.(Nativ),          # specify between-subject variable
      within=.(Algos,Audios),    # specify within-subject variables
      detailed=TRUE,             # get a detailed table that includes SS
      type=3)                    # type of SS
```

After that, I'm carrying out a Tukey's HSD as a post-hoc test to specifically rank the performance of the 3 algorithms.

Given that some of the assumptions required by the ANOVA are failed by the data (OK, I include the Huynh-Feldt correction, but that shouldn't take care of departures from homogeneity of variances), I tried to look into non-parametric equivalent of the analysis I'm carrying out.
To be honest, I had the impression that a lot of incorrect/imprecise/misleading information is available on the matter (some people recommend different methods having completely different assumptions for the same problem), so it gets quite difficult to understand what methodology to use without a deep understanding of the subject.

Therefore, I'd like to have the expert opinion of the people in this forum, so that I may be able to run a separate non-parametric analysis on my data and check that the conclusions are similar to those I obtained with rmANOVA.

PS: From what I understood, non-parametric methods should not work well to calculate interaction effects, but this is not *that* important to me, at the moment.

[1] ITU-T Rec. BS.1534-3, “Method for the Subjective Assessment of Inter-
mediate Sound Quality (MUSHRA),” International Telecommunication
Union, Geneva, Switzerland, Oct. 2015

Comment: Unless the departures from the model assumptions are large it probably does not matter. Sometimes transformation helps if there is a relationship between mean and variance.

Comment: And how would you define "large"?
So far, I carried the usual tests, like checking the QQ-plots and run the Shapiro test and point out that the normality is not satisfied.

Comment: I found a very recent release of an R package that might help me out.
The welchADF package (https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2017/RJ-2017-049/index.html) implements s Johansen’s formulation of the Welch-James test, including 1) the use of trimmed means and Winsorized variances to deal with non-normality, and 2), the use of bootstrap.

I hope this can be helpful.